# Make a specific external/guest users in SharePoint Online able to search persons

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad

We have an intranet based on SharePoint Online where we have a group of external/guests users from our sister intranet (also SPO). For these specific users, we want them to be able to do a personal search in our intranet. Is it possible to add these specific users to a group, and give the permissions to this group to be able to do a person search (or something similar)?

Comment: Welcome @typescriptBenginner! Are your sister intranet site and this site in the same Microsoft 365 tenant?

Comment: Thank you @BennySkogberg! They are different tenants.